# Set item in array using com.mongodb.client.model.Updates.set

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

I try to update an array element using MongoDB Java driver API method `com.mongodb.client.model.Updates.set` like this:

```
set(String.format("bag.items[%d]", idx), old.map(mo -> mo.frozen).orElse(null))
```

But instead of updating, the Item it creates a new field with the name "items[0]"

[image]

Comment: Please mention what is the query criteria for the update operation? Also, the MongoDB and the Java driver versions you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the correct syntax is

```
set(String.format("bag.items.%d", idx), old.map(mo -> mo.frozen).orElse(null))
```